# Why Do I Get An Error On A If Statement In Php Even Though The Statement Is Structured Correctly

Tags: php

I Get A Error Like This In Php On My If Statement Even Though The Statement Has No Visible Errors:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in CODE on line 11
Errors parsing CODE

here is my code:

```
    <?php
    // Include config file
    require_once "config.php";
     
    // Define variables and initialize with empty values
    $username = $password = $confirm_password = $email = "";
    $username_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";
    $emailweb = "@"
     
    // Processing form data when form is submitted
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

 
    // Validate username
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter a username.";
    } else{
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                /* store result */
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    $username_err = "This username is already taken.";
                } else{
                    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    
    // Validate password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter a password.";     
    } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 6){
        $password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }
    
    if(empty(trim($_POST["email"]))){
        $email_err = "Please Enter A Email."
    } else{
        $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    }
    
    // Validate confirm password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
        $confirm_password_err = "Please confirm password.";     
    } else{
        $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
        if(empty($password_err) && ($password != $confirm_password)){
            $confirm_password_err = "Password did not match.";
        }
    }
    
    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty(trim($_POST["email"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter a email.";     
    } elseif(strpos($email,$emailword) == false){
        $email_err = "Invalid Email.";
    } else{
        $emaIL= trim($_POST["email"]);
    }
        
        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password,email) VALUES (?, ?,?)";
         
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: login.php");
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
    }
    ?>

 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    <p>Please fill this form to create an account.</p>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
        </div>    
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($email)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $email; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <label>Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
        

        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
                </div>
                <p>Already have an account? <a href="login.php">Login here</a>.</p>
            </form>
        </div>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Please Help As This Is A Very Important Issue**
This Error Is Very Weird And I Dont How To Deal With It So Thanks In Advance

Comment: `$emailweb = "@"` <<< L@@K at what is missing here.

Comment: ^^^this. And in future please use an IDE or code editor which can highlight trivial errors like this for you immediately, before you even try to run the code. If it's really as important as you say, then you should take the time to find the correct tools to do the job.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a semicolon in the previous line.

```
$emailweb = "@";
```

Comment: omg im an idiot!